# What does it mean to take the spectral measure of a Laplacian and why is this useful?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I know (from [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure)) that a spectral measure $\pi$ on a measurable space $(X, M)$ is a mapping from $M$ to a certain set of orthogonal projections on a Hilbert space $H$. For example $\pi(X) = \text{id}_H$.

I read that one can additionally consider the spectral measure of the Laplacian of some function. I'm not sure what this means and couldn't find a reference. How does one turn the Laplacian into a measurable space? What do the orthogonal projections look like? What desirable properties does this give me?

I am not hitting the right search terms so this question is primarily a reference request asking where I can learn more about spectral measures *of the Laplacian* specifically.

Comment: What you should be looking up is the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators. The "spectral theorem" states that we can produce a projection-valued measure corresponding to any self-adjoint operator

Comment: Some of the "desirable properties" this measure gives you can be seen through the [section of your linked article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure#Application_in_quantum_mechanics) regarding quantum mechanics. Note that the Laplacian naturally arises in this context since the operator corresponding to the kinetic energy observable is
$$
\hat T = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2,
$$
where $\nabla^2$ denotes the Laplacian.